# Ajuda com operadores de comparação Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boa Tarde,
Estou fazendo um trabalho, do qual vou ter diversos formulários com um numero minimo e máximo e estou querendo criar uma função de verifica e evita a inserção de números fora da faixa pelo teclado, a minha função ficou desta forma

```js
$(':input[type="number"]').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var id = this.id;
  var min = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('min');
  var max = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('max');

  verificaTypeNumber(id, min, max);
});

function verificaTypeNumber(idInput, minValue, maxValue) {
  var aux = document.getElementById(idInput).value;

  if (aux == null || aux < minValue) {
    document.getElementById(idInput).value = minValue;
  } else if (aux > maxValue) {
    document.getElementById(idInput).value = maxValue;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="Teste" min="10" max="999" value="10">
```

Ao digitar um valor abaixo da faixa (no exemplo menor que "10") a função funciona e entra dentro do `if()`, porem para um valor acima da faixa (acima de 999), ela não funciona e não entra dentro do `else if()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `.value` de um input e os atributos `min` e `max` que estás a ler são *strings*. E por causa disso ele está a comparar texto e não numeros.

Repara na minha resposta que uso `Number` para converter texto (*strings*)  em numeros e assim a tua lógica já funciona.

Mudei também o que é passado à função, assim em vêz de chamares `document.getElementById(idInput)` 5 vezes, não chamas nenhuma e usas o `this` que é o elemento que queres.

```js
$(':input[type="number"]').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var min = Number(this.getAttribute('min'));
  var max = Number(this.getAttribute('max'));

  verificaTypeNumber(this, min, max);
});

function verificaTypeNumber(el, minValue, maxValue) {
  var aux = Number(el.value);

  if (aux == 0 || aux < minValue) {
    el.value = minValue;
  } else if (aux > maxValue) {
    el.value = maxValue;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="Teste" min="10" max="999" value="10">
```